# How to use linear regression to estimate parameters for this example?

Tags: machine-learning, regression

I am learning Machine Learning. and going through some videos. In that one slide came which I am not able to understand (Attached below).
This is related to Linear Regression.

[image]

In second image, it starts line from 0's place as value of theta0 is 0. but value of theta1 is 0.5, then why he kept points at (2,1) and (1,2)?

Based on given formula, how this line is going up and how it estimates points/value.

Comment: For each one point increase in x, y goes up by 0.5. That's what the numbers mean.

Comment: why he draw line at (2,1) point only?
Did he choose x as 2 randomly ?

Comment: Did he took random numbers for x in each test. (for first image 0, second image took 1, and for third one took 3)?

Answer (score 1):

Two green points - it's your real data, where set of `x` coordinates is values of your single feature and set of `y` - target values (for example `price of house`). Function `h_theta(x)` - is a hypothesis - you want to find a best linear function which would approximate (predict `y` by given `x`) **all of your points** as good as possible. So the line in the middle perfectly fits one point, but it doesn't fit the second point well.

First two images are showing how does a linear function look when one of the theta parameters is `0`.